# Bold Greek with stix?

Tags: bold, stix, boldsymbol, babel-greek

As one may observe, if one reactivates the stix package in the MWE below, the boldfacing of the classical Greek word `Aταραξια disappears.

Is there a way to keep stix and not lose the boldfacing of `Aταραξια`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek.polutoniko, portuguese]{babel}

%\usepackage{stix}

\newenvironment{greek}
{\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}}
    {\end{otherlanguage*}}
    
\begin{document}
                                
    \begin{greek}\textbf{<Ataraxia}\end{greek} e \textbf{felicidade}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stix itself does not seem to have bold Greek in text mode (although there are bold Greek math symbols). You can use a substitute font instead. A good option might be [Tempora](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tempora), which is explicitly designed as a "companion to Times font packages" for Greek and Cyrillic, i.e., it is a font that matches Times (and therefore Stix). It also fully supports Polutoniko.

The code below is adapted from the documentation of Tempora. Note that the order of the preamble is important: you should load the Stix package first and then substitute the LGR (i.e., Greek) part afterwards.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko, portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{stix}
\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}

\newenvironment{greek}
{\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}}
    {\end{otherlanguage*}}
    
\begin{document}
                                
    \begin{greek}\textbf{<Ataraxia}\end{greek} e \textbf{felicidade}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]